# Flexbox in Firefox: Items are not lined up properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This http://jsfiddle.net/7ra5oL77/ should line up the orange dots horizontally with the text underneath. 
The relevant items are:

```
<div class="draggable ui-widget-content"></div>
```

and

```
<div class="item">60°C</div>
```

This works in Chrome and Edge, but Firefox seem to not use the full width and there is a too big white space on the right side.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post all of your HTML and CSS in the question as well so we don't have to jump back and forth between StackOverflow and JSFiddle to help solve your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that I see is that firefox is recognizing your div.lines as items within the flexbox even though the are position absolute. If you pull them outside of the container or delete them altogether (I don't see their purpose), then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. I did not post the JavaScript but this will be a linegraph where you can drag the points with your mouse on the right place, the lines are connecting the dots together. I now put the lines in a seperate container and it works now in firefox too.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute positioned `.lines` mess up with the `space-around` alignment:

```css
#graph-containment-wrapper {
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

This seems a bug, because [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items) says

> An absolutely-positioned child of a [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) does not
>   participate in flex layout.

> The [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) property aligns [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) along the
>   [main axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-axis) of the current line of the flex container.

As a workaround, you can use [`auto` margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) to achieve the same effect without the interference of absolutely positioned elements:

```css
.draggable {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.lines {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
}
.draggable {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: n-resize;
  top: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.x-axis {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%
}
#graph-containment-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: white;
}
.graph {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.draw-area{
  width: 100%
}
.hlines{
  background-color: lightgray;
  width:100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: flex;
}
.hlines-container{
  display:flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 20rem;
  margin-top: -20rem
}
```

```html
<div class="graph">
  <div class="draw-area">
    <div id="graph-containment-wrapper">
      <div class="draggable ui-widget-content"></div>
      <div class="draggable ui-widget-content"> </div>
      <div class="draggable ui-widget-content"> </div>
      <div class="draggable ui-widget-content"> </div>
      <div class="draggable ui-widget-content"> </div>
      <div class="lines" id="myline0"></div>
      <div class="lines" id="myline1"></div>
      <div class="lines" id="myline2"></div>
      <div class="lines" id="myline3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hlines-container">
      <div class="hlines"></div>
      <div class="hlines"></div>
      <div class="hlines"></div>
      <div class="hlines"></div>
      <div class="hlines"></div>
      <div class="hlines"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="x-axis">
    <div class="item">20°C</div>
    <div class="item">30°C</div>
    <div class="item">40°C</div>
    <div class="item">50°C</div>
    <div class="item">60°C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```