# Make flex element ignore child element

Tags: css, html, flexbox

Is it possible to make a flex element ignore a child element so it's size does not affect the other elements?

For example, I have a wrapper with `display: flex`. It has a header, content, and footer.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header></header>
    <article></article>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

I want the wrapper to ignore the header tag (the header will be fixed to the top of the window). The article will be set to `flex: 1` so it takes up the rest of the space, forcing the footer to the bottom of the page. Here is some sample CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px; /* Accounts for header */
}

header {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

article {
    flex: 1;
}

footer {
    height: 50px;
}
```

I know I could just move the header outside of the wrapper but I have a lot of existing code that will make that a bit more difficult. Is what I am asking even possible?

Comment: Can you post a full working sample? (a snippet)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39069320/3597276

Comment: Are you working with Firefox?

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xvzbwksx/

Comment: That's exactly what I want. For some reason, I am having issues where Chrome is still trying to calculate my header into the flex elements. I am using Bootstrap and its fixed navbar, so the header element didn't actually have `position: fixed` so I wonder if that is part of the issue.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991051/absolutely-positioned-flex-item-is-not-removed-from-normal-flow-in-firefox-ie1

Answer (score 91):

In your .wrapper declare `flex-wrap: wrap`. Then for your header, you can add the style `flex-basis: 100%` which will force everything else down below the header.

Comment: @LisaCerilli, This is good information and a good solution to OP's problem, but it still doesn't answer the general question of how to *ignore* an element, which is why it is not the accepted answer, presumably.

Comment: Flex-basis is the only way you can force the child to behave like it's not part of the flexed content.

Answer (score 42):

Use `position: absolute` for the child element to exclude it from the flex calculations

Comment: Child elements ignores flex with this style. Therefore this should be the answer I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Use `flex: 0 0 100%;` to the child you want to be in a new line and add `flex-wrap: wrap` on the wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `flex-shrink: 0` on the child elements to keep them from shrinking to fill the container. And use `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container/wrapper so your children will wrap down.

Answer (score 1):

If trying to use `flex-direction:column`, the only thing that I found helpful for that is absolute positioning / with the corresponding padding.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-wrap: wrap` on the wrapper where you're having `display: flex`on.
That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the child elements that you want to run outside of flex the following properties:

`display: block; width: 100%;`